# How do I change the colour of text matching a regex in vim?

Tags: vim

Suppose I want to make all text that matches some regex persistently and automatically (and without affecting `/` searches) appear in a different color. How would I do this in `vim 7.4`?

Comment: You only need to search that regex, `vim` will highlight matched text for you.

Comment: @Gnouc I don't want to highlight the text, I want to change the color.

Comment: Do you mean syntax highlighting or the text matching a `/` search?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I want to change the color of text that matches a regex (so the text that *could* be simply highlighted with a `/` search)

Comment: What do you mean by "change the color"?

Comment: @MichaelHomer e.g. persistently make the text color purple instead of white, without changing the background and without interfering with common `/` searches.

Comment: If I understand what you mean now, this is what [`mark.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) does.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on exactly what you want, this is either what [`mark.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) or [general syntax highlighting](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) do.

Mark allows creating some number of distinct groups of highlighted patterns or extents. Specifying a particular regular expression is done with <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> by default. There's also a `:Mark` command. You can set the colourscheme using `:MarkPalette`.

Comment: `mark.vim` seems won't work with `vim 7.4`.

Comment: Works for me, but I can't comment on what else might get in the way.

Comment: @Gnouc: mark.vim supports Vim 7.2, 7.3, and also 7.4. The version given on vim.org is the _lowest_ supported one!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
highlight Test ctermfg=red
autocmd BufWinEnter * match Test /Power/
autocmd InsertEnter * match Test /Power/
autocmd InsertLeave * match Test /Power/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

Then when you open file, any text matches `Power` will be highlighted as red. This is a static way, you can write your own function to work with any pattern and color you want.

You can also use `mark.vim` but it is only tested with `vim` version 7.2 and lower.

Comment: Doesn't this interfere with other searches?

Comment: Yes, It will interfere, since when it's only a simple approach. We need more works if we want it really done.

Comment: That was his most important requirement, but it can be solved by using `2match` or `3match`.